# When is GAE standard python 2.7 runtime going away?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I know, I should port to PY3, but let's say I am unable to.

How much longer, apps written in PY2.7 will remain working on GAE, before support is completely removed and existing 2.7 apps won't work any more?

Answer (score 1):

I don't work for Google and only they can say, but from what I've seen, I expect that we have at least a few years.

Many people are in your position, and Google likely doesn't want to screw us over, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official statement from Google as of now as to when Python 2 will be deprecated, however, official support for Python 2 has been stopped since January of this year, so it is advised to work with Python 3 as soon as possible, although Google always does give notice in great advance beforehand. So I would advise to start migrating when you can and wait for a communication from Google to have an exact date.